# Bluetooth AR3012 0489:e076 doesn't find the devices

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, atheros

I have a laptop Acer v15 with Qualcom Atheros bluetooth and Logitech M557 mouse, which worked well initially. Then after disconnecting the mouse, my bluetooth adapter can't find any bluetooth devices nearby (I've also tried the Samsung s4). Now I'm using the Elementary OS, however the same thing was on Ubuntu 15.04 and Mint 17.1 when I tried them before installing the Elemetary.

I'm quite new to Linux, these are the data I've found so far:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)


$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


$ hciconfig
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: C0:38:96:6C:06:7E  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:1725 acl:0 sco:0 events:164 errors:0
    TX bytes:3394 acl:0 sco:0 commands:151 errors:0



$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
$
```

So from what I see, I have a bluetooth adapter, which is recognizable by the OS, it's turned on, however it can't find anything.

Upd: the lsusb output:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b474 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0489:e076 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Upd2: Added this as a bug to launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1462614

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adapter **0489:e076** is not supported by linux kernel yet. 
It is **AR3012**.

In case you have a similar problem, when some hardware is not supported, just report it to launchpad.

**When you report issues correctly, you help all people who use same device.**

Bug reported is created by running

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

Then create a launchpad account, if you do not have one and follow instructions in browser. Apport will collect necessary information about your system and will add it to the report.

Unfortunately it does not add important information about usb devices.
So I recommend to add also output of `usb-devices` command if the report relates to usb.

*This specific* issue [has been reported to launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1462614) and I made a fix.

The patch will reach stable Ubuntu kernels in a month or two.

In the meantime you can install a [fixed driver from launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-lp1462614-dkms_0.1_all.deb)

You will also have to upgrade `linux-firmware` package to get new Atheros firmware. I also [added it to launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012_all.deb).

So you need to download and install these two deb files, then turn off computer and on.

Bluetooth will work.

Thanks Igor Bagayev for testing!

The temproray solution will work only for this specific device. If you have another code in `lsusb` create your own bug report.

Comment: Added the bug report.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1462614

Comment: I added patch and built a deb for testing.

Comment: @Pilot6, unfortunately it's still not resolved for me. Could you please check the details I have put here? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1462614/comments/34

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours of trying to fix this, I've found a solution:
I copied all the files from Windows (Program Files\Common Files\QCA-Bluetooth) to Elementary's /lib/firmware/ar3k folder.

Got the solution from here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1425252

Upd: Sorry for the mess, that's not a solution. It doesn't work after reboot

Comment: You don't even know which BT adapter OP has.

Comment: What does OP mean?

Comment: I do know what BT adapter I have from lspci, it's
Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: Your answer is not related to the question. You can boot to Windows, the firmware will load, then reboot (no poweroff) to linux. Bluetooth will work. That's not a solution.

Comment: If you want a fix for you too, you can ask a similar question. Your adapter may be supported.

Comment: @Pilot6 There is a patched kernel by Joshua Salisbury in the bug report he linked to but that kernel may not have had the xhci fix yet that was added to 3.16.0-32

Comment: @Jeremy31   This is another adapter anyway

Comment: @Pilot6 The guy that answered is the OP

Comment: @Jeremy31 Oops. Did not notice it. Anyway I can fix it, unless there is a wrong firmware again. We need a new bug report. And a test.

Comment: @Pilot6 Aha, I see. So it wasn't the file copying that restored the bluetooth, but the fact that I rebooted to Windows and back. 
I'll install the Ubuntu and send a report as you described, thanks a lot

Comment: And the patch will fix bt for elementary too. But it needs to go upstream first.